# Drawing rectangle on image opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have loaded an image using opencv libraries in python and now i want to draw a rectangle using mouse but while drawing the rectangle the rectangle should be visible so that the person drawing it can place it in a way so that the object of interest is completely in rectangle but my code is producing not the desired output

my code is

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2

baseDir = '/home/aman/Downloads/shirt/'

filenames = next(os.walk(baseDir))[2]

drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
mode = True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve
ix,iy = -1,-1
tx,ty = -1,-1

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing,mode
    print 'aman'
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    drawing = True
    ix,iy = x,y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    if drawing == True:
        if mode == True:
            #cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
            cv2.line(img, (ix,iy),(ix,y), 255, 1, 8, 0)
            cv2.line(img, (ix,iy),(x,iy), 255, 1, 8, 0)

            cv2.line(img, (ix,y),(x,y), 255, 1, 8, 0)
            cv2.line(img, (x,iy),(x,y), 255, 1, 8, 0)
        else:
            cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    drawing = False
    if mode == True:
        #cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,y),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),-1)
    else:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)

img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == ord('m'):
    mode = not mode
    elif k == 27:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

`

but the output produced is something like
[image]

I dont want this kind of behaviour i just want a single rectangle not for every movement. I know i should modify the code in mouse move event but the problem is how to do that so that when the person is moving the mouse he is able to see the complete rectangle and when he releases the button the rectangle should be fixed ?

Comment: OpenCv draws the line directly into your image data. Either copy and restore for every new rectangle or use a proper Gui Toolkit.

Comment: I really don't know how to do this in Python (hence the comment), but the idea is to draw each intermediate rectangle by doing XOR between the line color and the image color at each pixel. Then, before you draw the next rectangle, XOR again with the line color to undo the previous rectangle. In C++ you'd do this with [LineIterator](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator). Only on the final rectangle do you draw it normally in the final color.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of the process as rendering in any other rendering API like OpenGL: to put something on the screen you clean it and then draw upon the clean area.

In this context cleaning means bringing back the original image. Drawing upon it means adding your rectangles or whatever.

So, what i recommend is creating a `draw` method that only takes care of this. Call it whenever a change to the rendering target is meant to be made.

A quick snippet (not real python, just pseudocode):

```
source_image = Mat()
image = Mat()
rect = Rect()

# general logic and stuff ...

# set a mouseCallbackListener
def listener(evt):
    rect.x = evt.x   # uptade de rect properly (...)
    draw()

# apply the drawing logic
def draw():
    image = source_image.clone()
    rectangle(image, rect, Scalar(0,255,0), 1, 8, 0)
    imshow(WINDOW_NAME, image)
```

If you wish to see a real example, here's a C++11 code that let's you draw more than one triangle and then get their centers as output in response to keyboard input: https://gist.github.com/cirocosta/9f7a57bddb40c4e5cbca

[image: Example of Rectangle Selection]

Answer (score 1):

I'm just working at the same problem. The solution i found is based on:

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/

Everything works, but i'm a little bit unhappy about the global variables.

```
# initialize the list of points for the rectangle bbox,
# the temporaray endpoint of the drawing rectangle
# the list of all bounding boxes of selected rois
# and boolean indicating wether drawing of mouse
# is performed or not
rect_endpoint_tmp = []
rect_bbox = []
bbox_list_rois = []
drawing = False

def select_rois(img):
"""
Interactive select rectangle ROIs and store list of bboxes.

Parameters
----------
img :
    image 3-dim.

Returns
-------
bbox_list_rois : list of list of int
    List of bboxes of rectangle rois.
"""
# mouse callback function
def draw_rect_roi(event, x, y, flags, param):
        # grab references to the global variables
        global rect_bbox, rect_endpoint_tmp, drawing

        # if the left mouse button was clicked, record the starting
        # (x, y) coordinates and indicate that drawing is being
        # performed. set rect_endpoint_tmp empty list.
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            rect_endpoint_tmp = []
            rect_bbox = [(x, y)]
            drawing = True

        # check to see if the left mouse button was released
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            # record the ending (x, y) coordinates and indicate that
            # drawing operation is finished
            rect_bbox.append((x, y))
            drawing = False

            # draw a rectangle around the region of interest
            p_1, p_2 = rect_bbox
            cv2.rectangle(img, p_1, p_2, color=(0, 255, 0),thickness=1)
            cv2.imshow('image', img)

            # for bbox find upper left and bottom right points
            p_1x, p_1y = p_1
            p_2x, p_2y = p_2

            lx = min(p_1x, p_2x)
            ty = min(p_1y, p_2y)
            rx = max(p_1x, p_2x)
            by = max(p_1y, p_2y)

            # add bbox to list if both points are different
            if (lx, ty) != (rx, by):
                bbox = [lx, ty, rx, by]
                bbox_list_rois.append(bbox)

        # if mouse is drawing set tmp rectangle endpoint to (x,y)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and drawing:
            rect_endpoint_tmp = [(x, y)]


# clone image img and setup the mouse callback function
img_copy = img.copy()
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw_rect_roi)

# keep looping until the 'c' key is pressed
while True:
    # display the image and wait for a keypress
    if not drawing:
        cv2.imshow('image', img)
    elif drawing and rect_endpoint_tmp:
        rect_cpy = img.copy()
        start_point = rect_bbox[0]
        end_point_tmp = rect_endpoint_tmp[0]
        cv2.rectangle(rect_cpy, start_point, end_point_tmp,(0,255,0),1)
        cv2.imshow('image', rect_cpy)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # if the 'c' key is pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord('c'):
        break
# close all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

return bbox_list_rois
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve that in black background with the following code:-

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
mode = True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve
ix,iy = -1,-1

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
  global ix,iy,drawing,mode

  if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
      drawing = True
      ix,iy = x,y

  elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    if drawing == True:
        if mode == True:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),3)
            q=x
            w=y
            if q!=x|w!=y:
                 cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,0,0),-1)
        else:
            cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)

  elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    drawing = False
    if mode == True:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,255,0),2)

    else:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)

img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

while(1):
 cv2.imshow('image',img)
 k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
 if k == ord('m'):
    mode = not mode
 elif k == 27:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[This was achieved by overlapping older rectangles with solid fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLjgn.png)

Though if u want it over image , I can suggest watermarks

> http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/07/transparent-overlays-with-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

I always wanted a way to drag a rectangle easily on an image while using opencv.  So I finally wrote this simple library in python using opencv to do just that. Check out the implementation [here](https://github.com/arccoder/opencvdragrect).

https://github.com/arccoder/opencvdragrect

If anyone tries it. I would be happy hear some comments on how I can improve it or any issues that you found in it.